# Magento all link url not proper

Tags: magento

Hi all I am new to magento i stuck with some trival error i.e

all css, js etc url coming like below

```
091fashion.comskin/adminhtml/default/default/images/ajax-loader.gif
```

instead of

```
091fashion.com/skin/adminhtml/default/default/images/ajax-loader.gif
```

Please guide me what to do i already changed the path on database in table  mg_core_config_data with http://091fashion.com/

please help thanks

Answer (score 0):

In that table search for:

```
web/unsecure/base_url
web/secure/base_url
```

And make sure the link from there ends with a "/".
Clean the cache and then test it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a access of database then go to your magento database and find core_config_data table and you can see your main domain path which is in

```
web/unsecure/base_url
web/secure/base_url
```

so if your url is like this **www.xyz.com** then replace with   **www.xyz.com/**

add **/** end of the link and your done with it. hope it helps :)